# Can you identify this set that seems to be from LEGO Star Wars? Dark grey circle pieces and clear canopy?

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help identify what set this is from please?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curved roof tiles are a key to finding this set:

[76003 - Superman: Battle of Smallville](https://brickset.com/sets/76003-1/Superman-Battle-of-Smallville)

It's missing a fair few pieces, but that's the core of the flyer:[image]

The clone trooper and the gold chest are rogue parts here ;)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Yes the clone trooper and chest were added by my son - the chest contains very important jewels so I wasn't allowed to touch it :-)