# What Lego set is this from? minifig-scale bumpy grey spaceship

Tags: set-identification

I got this in a bundle but no idea what set it's from.  Thanks for your help

[image: minifig-scale bumpy grey spaceship]

Comment: Actually, this question is a duplicate of https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/can-you-identify-this-set-that-seems-to-be-from-lego-star-wars-dark-grey-circle/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you identify this set that seems to be from LEGO Star Wars? Dark grey circle pieces and clear canopy?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/can-you-identify-this-set-that-seems-to-be-from-lego-star-wars-dark-grey-circle)

Comment: I vote to leave this question open, even if it is a duplicate. The OP has no chance to find a previous answer because he/she does not know what to look for in the first place, there is just a picture of the set. Therefore, points for question and answer should be awarded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's part of [set 76003-1: Superman Battle of Smallville](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76003-1):

[image: Set image]

Found by searching [sets which contain a 8x6 bubble canopy](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98102&in=S). Remember, [searching for the rarest pieces in a set](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-of-parts) tends to make the search easier.